# Cardinality or Selectivity Estimation of queries in databases

Tags: database, optimization, estimation, cardinality

It seems that cardinality estimation is a widely used technique in databases for selecting the best execution plan, is there any open source tool for cardinality estimation of a sql query? I want to get the estimated row numbers of the output dataset of each operator(join/group by etc.)

Comment: The estimate comes from a *specific implementation* (and usually using some heuristic or probe of the actual data hence the need to "ensure updated statistics"); anyway, various databases such as SQL Server can generate query plan information that already include quite a breakdown with cardinality estimates.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve. It is tool-specific? Each RDBMS with a cost-based optimizer (and most of the moderns RDBMS do have one) have this functionality built-in. MySQL and PostgreSQL are open-source, so you could knock yourself out looking at their code...

Comment: Well, actually I want to get the cardinality estimation of each stage (join/group by etc.), by my code if it's possible, any database compatible with SQL92 will be fine since my query won't be very complex. Of course, checking out the code of MySQL or PostgreSQL is a possible solution, but I think it will be a heavy work, I'm looking into H2 now.. Any other suggestions are welcomed , thanks!